# How can I simulate the same scenario 3 times on NetLogo?

Tags: simulation, netlogo, patch

I have a simulation for a fire-evacuation, and the fire starts form different sources.
I want to simulate the exit with the least number of injuries, while having 3 exits it's 3 scénarios.
But my issue, is that the simulate each exit with different fire sources. How can I fix the same scenario for three simulations ? 
Here is the code :

```
 to run-all
  clear-all
  let temp (list ("left") ("right") ("top"))
  foreach temp [
    [a] ->
    setup
    set finished 1
    if a = "left" [
      while [finished = 1] [
      go-to-left
      ]
    ]
if a = "right" [
      while [finished = 1] [
      go-to-right
      ]
    ]
if a = "top" [
      while [finished = 1] [
      go-to-top
      ]
    ]


  ]
end
```

Comment: The usual way to run a model multiple times with different settings is to use BehaviorSpace, http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/behaviorspace.html

Comment: I'm interpreting his question to wanting to run the exact same "random" setup of agents with different starting positions of fires or different exits available for the people to head towards.  I'm not sure - waiting for him to reply!  If that's so, then Behavior space isn't useful -- hmm, or maybe if the setups are put in a chooser widget, Behavior space would help -- but he might still want a random-seed set for the head-to-head comparison of outcomes,

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need to change the code you posted here.  The place to look is in your "setup" code, which you did not post.

Probably in your setup code you use "random" to create places for people to stand, so what you need is to have "random" generate the exact same locations for each of many different passes, so you can compare the different exits with the same starting conditions.

The way to do that is to set the "seed" that "random" will use ( secretly )  to exactly the same seed at the start of each pass you want to be identical.

Then if you want a new series of runs with different random locations,  change the seed to a different number and use that at the start of each run

The command to do that is described in the User dictionary under "random-seed", where it also tells you See the Random Numbers section of the Programming Guide for more details.